# Elixir: Tail-call optimized recursion inside conditionals

Tags: elixir

Will my function below be tail-call optimized in Elixir?

```
def poller(func, args, interval) do
  case apply(func, args) do
    :done -> :done
    :try_again ->
      :timer.sleep(interval)
      poller(func, args, interval)
  end
end
```

From what I've read in beginner literature, the optimization applies only when the recursive call is the "very last thing" the function does.

How does this work inside other conditionals? e.g. What if my recursion call is the last thing inside an `if`, but there's an `else` block after?

Comment: I don't know how aggressive Elixir's TCO is, but that `poller` call is definitely in tail position, so it's eligible for tail call optimization. The exact definition of "very last thing", as you've just discovered, is surprisingly complicated and involves control flow graphs, but generally speaking "last thing in a conditional which is the last thing in a function" is still fine. Obviously, "last thing in a loop" is a problem since the loop might repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your example is valid tail recursion. Using tail recursion with conditionals is actually a very common pattern, it is even necessary in most cases except if you want an infinite loop.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ca6f5d7332ef16ab388427c642b9864927bf3c66/lib/elixir/lib/list.ex#L1378-L1386) from the standard library (`List.zip/1`).

Here is [another one](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ca6f5d7332ef16ab388427c642b9864927bf3c66/lib/elixir/lib/list.ex#L1364-L1373) (`List.pop_at/3`): note there is no `case` expression, but multiple clause functions are actually [translated as `case`](https://www.erlang.org/blog/core-erlang-by-example/#more-than-one-clause) during compilation to core erlang. This is actually the same thing.

`if` or `cond` are the same, since they are translated as `case` as well.
The important point is that the recursive call can only be called as the last thing of each conditional branch.